# Parallax background isn't tiled correctly

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm trying to make a simple parallax scrolling effect on a small div, however when you're scrolling down you can see the line where the background repeats.
You can see the effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/c1vr6nrk/1/embedded/result/

I tried editing the following code but I can't seem to make it work correctly:

```
(function(){

  var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
      speed = 0.5;

  window.onscroll = function(){
    [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

      var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

      el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

    });
  };

})();
```